# Is there any use of Android:debuggable=true when you don't have any source code?

Tags: android, debugging, apk

Say I have BHIM.apk and I want to debug this. Since I don't have the source code, so can I see the logs generated by Android?

Answer (score 0):

if BHIM.apk build type debug, you need: 
 - install android studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/install 
 - install BHIM.apk on real device and connect to laptop(pc, bla bla) via USB 
 - read logcat: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: I did not get you what you want to say. Could you eleaborate your first sentence more.

Comment: You must first install the Android studio IDE to view logcat from it.